# A holomorphic function $f: D \to \overline{D}$, where $D=\{z \in \Bbb C~:~|z|<1\}$, such that $f(1/2)=0$ and $|f'(1/2)| =4/3$

Tags: complex-analysis

I was looking for a holomorphic function $f: D \to \overline{D}$, where $D=\{z \in \Bbb C~:~|z|<1\}$, such that $f(1/2)=0$ and $|f'(1/2)| =4/3$. I can't reject the possibility via Schwarz-Pick Lemma since $|f'(a)|\leq \frac{1-|f(a)|^2}{1-|a|^2}=4/3$ for $a=1/2$. Further, I tried with the form $$f(z)=cz^n+d,$$ for $n=1,2,3,...$ with $|c|+|d| \leq 1$. But the attempts were failure.

Can we suggest some examples?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there exists such a function. Indeed we can use Schwarz lemma for this. Following is the “background” (outline) of the proof/idea.

Given $f: D \to \overline{D}$ holomorphic such that $f(1/2)=0$ and $|f’(1/2)|=4/3.$ Let $a=1/2$ and define $\phi_a(z)=\frac{a-z}{1-\overline{a}z}$ which is an automorphism of unit disc with $\phi_(a)=0$ and $\phi_a^{-1}=\phi_a$ (self-inverse).

Consider $g(z)=f(\phi_a(z))$ which is holomorphic on $D$ and $|g(z)|\leq 1.$ Note that $g’(0)=f’(\phi_a(0))\phi_a’(0)=f’(1/2)(|a|^2-1)$ implying that $|g’(0)|= 1.$ Using Schwarz lemma, we have that $g(z)=cz$ for some $|c|=1.$ Consequently $f(z)=c\phi_a(z)=c \frac{a-z}{1-\overline{a}z}=c \frac{1-2z}{2-z}$ which satisfies the desired properties.

Comment: You have a presupposition that such an $f$ exists, right?

Comment: No, you just work with the function $f(z)=\frac{1-2z}{2-z}.$ I provided you the idea of how it might come into existence.

Comment: How can a mobious transformation $T(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ is self invertible unless $b=c=0$ and $a=d$?

Comment: No, that is not true!

Comment: But u've mentioned $\phi_a^{-1}=\phi_a$.

Comment: For this particular automorphism, it is true.

Comment: But, for $f(z)=\frac{1-2z}{2-z}$, it is $b=c \neq 0$ and $a \neq d$, right?